# Powershell script to set/update existing managed properties in sharepoint (Not create them or get them)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

has anyone used this method, i have been trying to work with it, i have been successful in setting description and retrievable only , the rest of the properties such as searchable,sortable etc have boolean values but i cant set any of them does any one have the correct code to using it. thanks

```
$newmp =Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication 
$ssa -Identity $newname -Name $newname  -Description $newDescription 
-Retrievable $newcsvRetrievable 

$newmp.FullTextQueriable= ([bool]::Parse($newFullTextQueriable));
$newmp.Searchable = $newSearchable;
$newmp.HasMultipleValues = ([bool]::Parse($newHasMultipleValues));
$newmp.Refinable = ([bool]::Parse($newRefinable));
$newmp.Queryable= ([bool]::Parse($newQueryable));
$newmp.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the official article [Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spenterprisesearchmetadatamanagedproperty?view=sharepoint-ps), it doesn't allow you to update such as searchable,sortable etc properties through this particular command.

You can use the PowerShell below to update search metadata managed properties.

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication;
$mp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $ssa -Identity $name;

$mp.Searchable = $true;
$mp.Queryable = $true;
$mp.Sortable = $true;
$mp.Retrievable = $true;
$mp.Refinable = $true;
$mp.Update();
```